# SQL rolling period of 20 days

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, rolling-computation

I was wondering what is the best way to find, if over any continuous period of 20 days, the number of events exceeded 10.

I am trying to write an exception report but cannot figure out a logic besides using a loop.

I have included the schema for the table.

```
ID       |StartDate       |EndDate       |Area


---------+---------+---------+---------

12       |01-02-2013       |05-02-2013       |A12

14       |06-02-2013       |12-02-2013       |A13

15       |11-02-2013       |19-02-2013       |A14

19       |16-02-2013       |26-02-2013       |A15

21       |21-02-2013       |05-03-2013       |A16

24       |01-02-2013       |05-02-2013       |A17

26       |06-02-2013       |12-02-2013       |A18

28       |11-02-2013       |19-02-2013       |A19

30       |16-02-2013       |26-02-2013       |A20

33       |21-02-2013       |05-03-2013       |A21
```

I have got a partial solution:
'

```
'DECLARE @START AS DATE
DECLARE @END AS DATE
SET @START= '20130201'
SET @END= '20130204'
SELECT     n.EVENT_DATE,
                          (SELECT     SUM(SESSIONS) AS Total_Sessionsn 
                            FROM          dbo.[Session]
                            WHERE      (EVENT_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-20,n.EVENT_DATE)     AND n.EVENT_DATE)
                            GROUP BY AREA_CODE, SITE_CODE) AS Sessions         
FROM         [dbo].[Session] AS n
WHERE     EVENT_DATE BETWEEN @START
 AND DATEADD(d,20+dbo.HolidayCount(@END,DATEADD(d,20,@END)) ,@END )'
```

Got IT. For anyone interested in finding the date 20 working days from now, I have added the solution below. :) (I feel stupid!)

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1  [SK_CAL]
      ,[CAL_DATE]
      ,[CAL_CODE]
      ,[CAL_VALUE]
      ,[CAL_OPEN]
      ,[CAL_CLOSE]
FROM 
(SELECT TOP 20 [SK_CAL]
      ,[CAL_DATE]
      ,[CAL_CODE]
      ,[CAL_VALUE]
      ,[CAL_OPEN]
      ,[CAL_CLOSE]
  FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[tbCalendar]
  WHERE (CAL_DATE>'20130201' AND CAL_VALUE=1)
  ORDER BY SK_CAL ASC) n
  ORDER BY SK_CAL DESC
```

Comment: Does each ID number identify an event?

Comment: How do you define start date of "continious period": today or event date?

Comment: Start of any event -19 days would be one rolling 20 day period and similarly last day + 19 days would be another 20 day period.

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking. These are multiple events, potentially concurrent, right? Are you looking for the number of simultaneously occurring events at any given time?

Comment: My problem currently is how to do this for 20 working days instead of  20 days.The HolidayCount function idea was to count total holidays between start and end and add it to the end date. That dosen't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you're after. I start with a CTE that gets the earliest StartDate and latest EndDate to define the range. Then another CTE extrapolates all the dates between. Then for each date in the range I see how many events were active in the 20 days prior to and including that date. I determine that by checking if the event start or end dates occur within the rolling 20 day period or if the event start and end dates encapsulate the entire rolling 20 day period.

```
;with StartEnd as (
select 
    min(StartDate) StartRange, 
    max(EndDate) EndRange
 from 
    @Events
),
DatesInRange AS 
(
    SELECT StartRange AS RangeDate, dateadd(d,-19,StartRange) Rolling20Start from StartEnd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, RangeDate), DATEADD(DAY, -18, RangeDate)
    FROM DatesInRange, StartEnd
    WHERE RangeDate < EndRange
)
select
    RangeDate,
    count(*)
from 
    DatesInRange
    left join @Events e on 
        e.StartDate between Rolling20Start and RangeDate or 
        e.EndDate between Rolling20Start and RangeDate or
        (e.StartDate < Rolling20Start and e.EndDate > RangeDate)
group by
    RangeDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I have got a partial solution